# Last heartbeat older than x minutes - Cron issues

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

The cron tasks heartbeat doesn't appear to be active in my Magento. I'm not sure why this is, I use Plesk to control the server side of things and I've set the following scheduled task (with domain settings/scheduled tasks) in attempt to force the heartbeat. However, it doesn't seem to work. I'd really appreciate any assistance you can give.

Here's the setup:

Minute: */10
Hour: *
Day of Month: *
Month: *
Day of Week *
Command: wget http://www.mydomainhere.co.uk/cron.php

Cron (Scheduled tasks) in Magento admin has the following info (I haven't updated any of this):
Generate schedule every: 15
Schedule Ahead for: 1
Missed if not run within: 60
History clean up after: 120
Success history lifetime: 60
Failure history lifetime: 600
Mark jobs failed after: 120
Heartbeat task schedule: */5 * * * *

Any ideas?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
wget -O /dev/null http://www.domain.com/cron.php
```

For debug purposes you can set every 3-4 minutes instead of every 10 minutes. If everything is working properly - in your database in table cron_schedule you will see cron tasks. If this table is clean - something went wrong.

**upd.1**

Don't be afraid, your cron runs like clockwork. In your table you see, that cron started successfully and completed successfully.

You got an error "Last heartbeat older than x minutes". In my opinion its very specific issue and related to some 3rd party extension. Try to search on your host this phrase. For example using SSH:

> grep -rni 'Last heartbeat older than'

And upload full text of this method in your post.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response, what does the /dev/null addition do? The e-mail task appears to have scheduled after doing this but hasn't completed yet. So I will update again soon. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm still receiving the message 'heartbeat is older than one hour' despite this change. However, according to the scheduled tasks in Magento the tasks are being successfully executed.

Comment: Could you show one or several rows from your cron_schedule table. Also tell us your local time, server time (write in console date) and mysql server time (execute query SELECT now(); )

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me. Local time is GMT (London) currently 17:06. Server time is 17:06. MySQL server time is 18:06. Image of rows here - http://s9.postimg.org/ep23e0jnz/mysqlrows.png

Comment: Sorry, read once again the topic. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql

Comment: Hello, do you want me to perform these actions and report the time or should I be setting the time on the SQL to the same as the server? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, hope it will help.

Comment: Change these settings. It still seems to be showing as if the heartbeat is not running. However the e-mail schedule seems to be running? Appreciate your help so far. Wonder if you or anyone else has any more thoughts...

Comment: updated.........